# Why is Cisco router PPPoE client configuration so complicated?

Tags: cisco, networking, internet, wan, pppoe

In some routers like Ubiquiti's *UniFi Security Gateway*, when you want to connect to internet via PPPoE, all you have to do is go to the web GUI or controller, go to WAN settings, hit the dropdown button, select PPPoE from the choices (Static, DHCP, PPPoE), input username and password, then save. It's all that easy.

But when it comes to Cisco router things get so complicated. Just like this one:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/long-reach-ethernet-lre-digital-subscriber-line-xdsl/asymmetric-digital-subscriber-line-adsl/4105-2600pppoe-4105.html

Why can't we just go to the interface, configure it as PPPoE client mode, then input username and password?

Comment: That's the difference between a GUI designed for people who don't know what they're doing, and a CLI designed for people that do. Yes, there are many more steps to the CLI, but the same thing gets done for you behind that GUI.

Comment: Instead of mocking a beginner you better at least try to help.

Comment: I'm not mocking you, I'm stating a fact. UniFi is designed for non-networking types. Their Edge line is geared towards the networking professional. (ISPs, actually) Almost everything Cisco makes is geared toward professional use/management, 'tho there have been some half-hearted attempts to make GUIs -- cisco configuration assistant, ASDM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices and configuration methods offer more control over the inner workings of protocols than others. More control requires more effort.